# How to ignore (null or 0) values in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table named (sale):

| category | amount | currency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cat1 | 10,000 | USD |
| cat2 | 5,000 | ERU |
| cat3 | 15,000 | SAR |
| cat2 | 30,000 | USD |
| cat1 | 45,000 | SAR |
| cat3 | 7,000 | ERU |
| cat2 | 3,000 | ERU |
| cat4 | 0 | USD |

I wrote this query to get the results in the table below:
note: the query has subqueries from the same table:

```
SELECT  S.[Category]

       ,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM([Amount]),0)
           FROM SALE
          WHERE [Currency] = 'USD'
            AND SALE.[CategoryID] = S.[CategoryID]) AS 'Total_USD'
            
       ,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM([Amount]),0) 
           FROM SALE
          WHERE [Currency] = 'ERU'
            AND SALE.[CategoryID] = S.[CategoryID]) AS 'Total_ERU'
            
       ,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM([Amount]),0) 
           FROM SALE
          WHERE [Currency] = 'SAR'
            AND SALE.[CategoryID] = s.[CategoryID]) AS 'Total_SAR'
        
        FROM Sale AS S
        GROUP BY S.[CategoryID],S.[CategoryName]
```

results:

| category | Total USD | Total ERU | Total SAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cat1 | 10,000 | 0 | 45,000 |
| cat2 | 30,000 | 8,000 | 0 |
| cat3 | 0 | 7,000 | 15,000 |
| cat4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

My question is:
How to avoid (0) values if all subqueries return (null or zeros) value, like above in (cat4) .

I tried (Having) clause, but I have to write all subqueries again in (Having), which is not a good thing to do.

Comment: Why not use conditional aggregation instead? Then you can use a `HAVING`.

Comment: You can filter before grouping with a simple `FROM Sale AS S WHERE S.Amount > 0` predicate in the where clause. Btw, you don’t need all these sub-queries to conditionally SUM by currencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch to conditional aggregation, which would be way more performant anyway, then you can use a `HAVING`. As you want to exclude the row with `'EUR'` you need to use a `CASE` expression in it:

```sql
SELECT S.Category,
       SUM(CASE currency WHEN 'USD' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS USD,
       --SUM(CASE currency WHEN 'EUR' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS EUR, --Seems you don't want EUR rows
       SUM(CASE currency WHEN 'SAR' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS SAR,
       SUM(CASE currency WHEN 'ERU' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS ERU
FROM dbo.Sale S
GROUP BY S.Category
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN currency IN ('USD','SAR','ERU') THEN amount END) != 0;
```

As it seems that the currency `'EUR'` was a typographical error, you may just want:

```sql
HAVING SUM(amount) != 0;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you solved my problem.
BTW, (EUR) it just a writing mistake :) , I edited it to (ERU).
Thank you again.

Comment: If that's the case you probably don't need conditional aggregation in the `HAVING`, @Jassom .

Comment: You're right, at least there will be a column > 0,   
because no record in the main table will be added if the amount is 0,  
thank you for reply @Larnu